# Kubuntu 18.04 not starting after shutdown. Stuck after splash screen

Tags: boot, kubuntu, startup, amd-graphics

HP pav g6, i3, 3gb ram, Radeon hd 6470M
Kubuntu 18.04 dual boot with windows 7.
Using Kubuntu for almost a year.

Issue: After splash screen it's stuck at black screen. Nothing responds except when I just press(not holding) the power button, again splash screen comes and it shuts down.

**Activities before the issue:**

Tried to open amd ccc but it said no driver found though I installed it. So ran the command `aticonfig --initialize`. Nothing happened. For my course, installed Drracket and used firefox for sometime. While shutting down:

1. Ran `shutdown` command from konsole.
2. It showed "system will shutdown at . So again tried to shutdown from Leave menu. Shutdown happened normally.
3. After that when I try to boot again, this issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information as with this much, only few things can be deducted.
One thing i would like to say is to use `shutdown now` instead of `shutdown` to immediately poweroff the system safely.

#### Few questions to help elaborate the problem :-

- Did you upgrade the kernel or system ? It is rare but could be that kernel was not updated or grub hook did not work after update.
- Did you disable the `legacy boot` in your bios or it got disabled unknowingly ? Maybe after a windows update ? Please check it out. This and if any option like `boot only UEFI` got enabled ?
- Check the system health with following tools :-

  - Storage(HDD) with [SMARTMONTOOLS](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/LiveCDs)
  - Memory with

    - if booting in BIOS mode - [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/)
    - if booting in UEFI mode - [memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)
- Disable secure boot was enabled in bios accidently after system update in windows.
- Disable fast boot if it is enabled in windows. Windows is cheesy and acts funny sometimes.
- Disable hibernate in windows. unless you are using it extensively.

Let me know if it helps you or you could find something that may help us moving in a direction. :-)